# onChange event testing issue in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

While trying to test the onchange functionality getting the error like "The given element does not have a value setter"
This is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nej1p.png)

And the corresponding tsx code :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCKfu.png)

PFB error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ge61.png)

so the code coverage is failing and its highlighting in pink color.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuQ2y.png)

I tried with this way also

```
const notesChange= screen.getByTestId("notesChange"); 
  fireEvent.change(notesChange, {
    target: { value: 'testpassword' },
   });
```

but not working. Pls help!!!